# Camel Alchemy Sound Design

Tags: design, keyboard

Hi guys,

Can you help me on this one? It's been some time that I wanted to broaden my options in sound design so I've got to the conclusion of starting with Camel Alchemy. Could you recommend me a keyboard/controler so I can use Alchemy?

Best regards,
Marco

Comment: ok, did some more research and came to the conclusion of Novation SL49mkII. Just ordered it and waiting for it to arrive in a week or so. 